# laravel, не работает sql запрос к таблице через форму

Tags: sql, laravel

Делаю магазин одежды - требуется реализовать фильтрацию товаров с учётом указанного диапазона цены и категории.
Имеется следующая форма:

```html
<form action="{{route('searchPrice')}}"  method="get">
<h4 class="shop-sidebar-title">Filter By Price</h4>
    <div class="price_filter mt-25">
    <label for="price_from">Цена от
    <input type="text" name="price_from" id="price_from" size="6" value="{{request()->price_from}}">
    </label>
    <label for="price_to">до
    <input type="text" name="price_to" id="price_to" size="6" value="{{request()->price_to}}">
    </label>
    <br>
    @foreach ($categoriesAll as $categoryAl)
    <input type="checkbox" name="searchCategory[]" id="searchCategory[]" value="{{ $categoryAl->id }}" class="input-pading">
      {{ $categoryAl->name }}
    @endforeach
    <button type="submit" id="but"> Показать</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

В контроллере делаю сведущую проверку:

```html
$searchCategory = $request->searchCategory;
            $categoriesAll = Categorie::all();
            $catView = Categorie::find($searchCategory);
            
            if ($request->filled('price_from') && $request->filled('price_to') && $searchCategory) {
                
                foreach ($searchCategory as $field) {
                    $productsSearch->where(('price','>=',$request->price_from) && ('price','<=',$request->price_to) && ('cat_id','=>',$request->$field))->orderBy('created_at');
                }
            }
            
            $productsSearch=$productsSearch->paginate(6);

            return view('pet-shop/shop-page',[
                'productsSearch'=>$productsSearch,
                'searchCategory'=>$searchCategory,
                'categoriesAll'=>$categoriesAll,
                'catView'=>$catView,
                'cart'=>$cart,
                'sum'=>$sum,
```

На что он сайт выдаёт ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В sql вставил этот запрос - всё работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне быть в данной ситуации?

Comment: По всей видимости я просто сглупил и не правильно написал запрос в контроллере. Был бы рад любой помощи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping

Вместо `&&` используй отдельные методы

```php
$productsSearch->where('price','>=',$request->price_from)
               ->where('price','<=',$request->price_to)
               ->where('cat_id','=>',$request->$field)
               ->orderBy('created_at');
```

или

```php
$productsSearch->where(function($query){
                   returm $query->where('price','>=',$request->price_from)
                                ->where('price','<=',$request->price_to)
                                ->where('cat_id','=>',$request->$field);
               })
               ->orderBy('created_at')
```

П.С.
Первый от второго отличается тем, что условия внутри функции дополнительно обернутся в скобки